# Generating a text file of the output through Java IO

Tags: java, io

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading the java files from the folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248847/reading-the-java-files-from-the-folder)

I have developed a java code that reads files from the folder chosen by the user. It displays how many lines of code are in each file, it reads only .java filesonly and final outcome is shown on console , I was thinking that output to be get displayed on console but along with a text file conataing the same information to be get stored on desktop also, please advise how to that and the name of the file that is generated its name is to be based on timestamp lets assume that name of the output file would be 'output06282012' and that text file should contain the same information that is shown on the console , here is my piece of code...

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("C:" + File.separator));
        chooser.setDialogTitle("FILES ALONG WITH LINE NUMBERS");
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
                if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {      Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
             File directory = new File(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath()); 
             int totalLineCount = 0;
             File[] files = directory.listFiles(new FilenameFilter(){
                  @Override
                  public boolean accept(File directory, String name) {
                      if(name.endsWith(".java"))
                      return true;
                    else
                      return false;              
                  }
                }
   );
              for (File file : files)
            {
                if (file.isFile())
                {    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
                    int lineCount = 0;
                     try
                    { for (lineCount = 0; scanner.nextLine() != null; lineCount++) ;
                          } catch (NoSuchElementException e)
                    {   result.put(file.getName(), lineCount);
                    totalLineCount += lineCount;  
                                    }


                } }
              System.out.println("*****************************************");
              System.out.println("FILE NAME FOLLOWED BY LOC");
              System.out.println("*****************************************");

            for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : result.entrySet())
            {   System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " ==> " + entry.getValue());
            }
            System.out.println("*****************************************");
            System.out.println("SUM OF FILES SCANNED ==>"+"\t"+result.size()); 
            System.out.println("SUM OF ALL THE LINES ==>"+"\t"+ totalLineCount);

             }     

    }
```

output that is displayed on console is to be stored in a text file  on desktop also, please advise how to that and the name of the file that is generated its name is to be based on timestamp lets assume that name of the output file would be 'output06282012' and that text file should contain the same information that is shown on the console

Comment: dont ever do this ` main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException` never throw an exception in main catch it!

Comment: @DavidKroukamp please advise what i can do in my piece of code to catch it

Comment: @DavidKroukamp please advise so that I can update my code

Comment: read up on try catch statements: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html and http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/Java%20Language/TryCatch.html

Answer (score 3):

I'd advice you to ask questions more precisely. From what I understand from your question, you want to write some information to a text file. To do this all you have to do is this -

```
try{

 java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
 System.out.println(new Timestamp(date.getTime())); 

BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C://Desktop//output"+new Timestamp(date.getTime())+".txt"));

out.write("some information");

out.close; 

}catch(IOException e){
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

So in your code inplace of `System.out.println();` statements you can use `out.write()`
statements to write to a text file.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: yeah I want near to this but not exactly this

Comment: So what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: output that ist displayed on console is to be stored in a text file  on desktop also, please advise how to that and the name of the file that is generated its name is to be based on timestamp lets assume that name of the output file would be 'output06282012' and that text file should contain the same information that is shown on the console

Comment: I have edited my answer. Just make sure you check the path of the desktop location.